# Read text from image iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, image, text, ocr

I have an image on my device which I capture from camera. The image has readable text. I want to convert that image into text i.e. get the text of image and display it.

I went through [Tesseract](https://github.com/nolanbrown/Tesseract-iPhone-Demo) demo, but not all the text of image is converted into text. I know that there are few paid SDK's like [ABBY SDK](http://www.abbyy.com/mobileocr/ios/?source=products) available for this, but I was looking for some free source.

Are there other SDKs available for the same?

Comment: HI @Nitish, i see that the question & answer is of 2012. from then ios library have enhanced much more. Have apple or any open source library developed from then? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this](https://github.com/nolanbrown/Tesseract-iPhone-Demo) for how to do something quick on iOS with Tesseract. I doubt you will get the accuracy you want though. So far I haven't found a good opensource solution because the iPhone camera is not well suited to this problem. There are a few online API options that do better.

Oh and one word of advice, don't pay for anything without trying it in your situation :)

Comment: This is the same link I have given. I already tried this demo. Text is not all fine.

Comment: Please suggest me the API's you know can help me.

Comment: There are many SO questions about this. You can search as well as I can. Your question asks for an SDK that does "the same", but the two services you have tried are very different. I don't know what you are planning. In general an API service will be slightly better, and in general a paid service will be better again. Which one is best for you depends on what your want to do.

Comment: You said there are a few online API options. Please suggest one.

Comment: http://ocrapiservice.com/   http://ocrsdk.com/